# When a homogeneous ideal is written as a product of two ideals, then each of two ideals is homogeneous?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-algebras

I know that in a graded domain, if a homogeneous element is written as a product of two elements, then each of two elements is also homogeneous. That is, the set of all the homogeneous elements of domain is saturated.

But I don't know if this argument also holds for ideal cases. For example, let $D$=$\bigoplus$$_{\alpha}$$D_{\alpha}$ be a graded domain. If a homogeneous ideal $I$ can be written as a product of two ideals, say $I=AB$, then is each of them also homogeneous?

Thank you for answering, in advanced.

Comment: The first thing you want to do here is to write down the definition of a homogeneous ideal.